# number of automorphisms of $ \mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n$

Tags: group-theory

How to find the number of group automorphisms of  $\mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n $
provided $m \, \& \, n $ are not relatively prime?

Comment: Why use the notation ${\mathbb Z}_m$ if you mean a group rather than a ring? That's not easy in general. The answer by Magidin to  math.stackexchange.com/questions/420884 shows how to calculate this when $C_m$ and $C_n$ have no common direct factor and the case when they do have a common direct factor is not too hard. But maybe you do not need a complete answer - did you have any particular values of $m$ and $n$ in mind?

Comment: @DerekHolt It's a very common notation for cyclic groups, actually. Using $C_m$ seems most common with those frequently using $p$-adics, rings, etc. in conjunction with groups, where notation starts getting ambiguous.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yes I have noticed that it is a very common notation for cyclic groups! But the fact that it can also denote a ring inevitably leads to ambiguities in some situations.